# media query doesn't work on devices

Tags: css, android-layout, media-queries, mobile-website, blogger

I am trying to apply media queries to a blogger template.

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px)
  { 
     //styling here
  }
```

This works fine on desktop browsers, when I am resizing the window. However when I test it on Mobile devices (android, iPhone) it doesn't work and shows the desktop version.
I had a look at [this](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) article, but nothing helps.

Comment: http://grmmphmedia.blogspot.fi/

Answer (score 4):

Are you specifying the `viewport` in the `html` .You will need this in order for the styles to render.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any iPhone other than the original, the width is 640px. And most Android phones these days are around there, if not more. So your `max-width: 600px` query is too narrow to apply to any of those phones.

You could correct this by increasing the `max-width` parameter to still exclude desktops while including phones. Taking Twitter Bootstrap's width for the mobile devices, you should try `max-width: 767px`.

Comment: Sorry, That's not it. Tried it with 767px. Tested on Galaxy II and iPhone. same result

Comment: I have it all here: http://grmmphmedia.blogspot.fi/ It works when I specify it for iPhone `@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-device-width: 480px) { }`

Comment: @grmmph Still dont work for me and your link dont allow us to go in.

Answer (score 0):

Seems at this point of time the code you are mentioning is not there in place and have the hidden the y axis.If at all it there is,then there is  only 1.You need to have more media queries for smaller widths.See my [blogspot site](http://www.ilovetrolls.org/)(its a custom domain so it does not have .blogspot),it has many media queries for much smaller widths different widths.

Set `max-width` and `max-height` for various elements in media queries for smaller widths and you should surely see it working.

Just a tip:To test,you need **not** open your website in android/ios,simply resize the window on your desktop or you this [site](http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php).